# Disabled Jbutton Swing not working well

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I have a problem with Swing JButtons. I'm working with Netbeans. When I disable a JButton in the GUI Builder it still fires the actions attached as events, i.e. I have a disabled button with an onClick trigger. No matter if disable, the trigger is working.

Somebody knows how to avoid this behavior? and the disabled jbutton fires the actions just when enabled?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the event handler code you are using? care to post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an ActionListener vs a MouseClickListener.

Technically, the user did click in your button. :)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a button.setEnabled(false) in code ? Maybe Netbeans is not setting the property properly...